# Why aren't both of my scripts in html working?

Tags: javascript, html

Only The function validateForm script is working in my html coding.

The menu script doesn't seem to work.

Can someone please try and identify this problem with my coding?

I can't link the Java externally because the web host that I want to publish it on won't support that.
My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Portolio</title>
<style>img { background:#8A0808;
padding:6px;
border:1px solid #999999; 
}

body {
font: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: dimgrey; 
color: #696969;
padding: 4px;
}

#main {
padding: 5px;
padding-left:  15px;
padding-right: 15px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

h1 {
font: Georgia, serif;
border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
color: #996600;
font-size: 30px;
}

table {
width:100%;
}

table, th , td {
border: 3px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}

th {
text-align: middle; 
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul#menu {
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

ul#menu li {
display: inline;
margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#menu li a {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #696969;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: black;
}</style>
</head>
<script>document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
"<p>&copy;  " + new Date().getFullYear() + " Copywright 2014 S.S.T.O. All rights         reserved.</p>";

document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Our_Portfolio.html'>Our Portfolio</a></li>" +
"</ul>";</script>

<script>
function validateForm() {

var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
//alert(x);
//alert(y);
if (y == null || x == "") {
    alert("All fields must be correctly filled out");
    return false;
}

if (x == "administrator" && y == "14b79d")
{
  document.forms["myform"].submit()
} else
{
  alert("User name and/or password is incorrect");
    return false;
}
}
</script>


<script>document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
"<p>&copy;  " + new Date().getFullYear() + " Copywright 2014 S.S.T.O. All rights    reserved.</p>";

document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='About.html'>About</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Our_Portfolio.html'>Our Portfolio</a></li>" +
"</ul>";</script>








<body>




<nav id="nav01"></nav>
<div id="main">
<h1>The SSTO's portfolio</h1>
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:78px; LEFT:1045px; WIDTH:195px; HEIGHT:65px"    SRC="https://lh6.ggpht.com/EIDo8hYVBfNxwtFxpAvJ0CGtxZENQ- Qctrz5lFn6EaQrp4HKFF_Qr4TwMxKwvaa5Ffbt37I=s170">
<p><strong> If you wish to view our amazing portfolio and receive monthly trading tips:      </strong></p>
<p>Please contact us at:</p>
<p> aryanmisra4@gmail.com</p>
<p>or, dggrishanov@hotmail.com</p>
<p>or, kencmg85@gmail.com</p>
<p>or, elias.kountouris@hotmail.com</p>
<h3>Thank You</h3>
<form name="myForm" action="Answered.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()"   method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>



<div></div>
<footer id="foot01"></footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code properly indented. It is much difficult to read a code like this.

Comment: Tip: there is no need to create a menu using javascript. Use HTML and css. You might also want to check the spelling of "copywright."

Comment: Is "14b79d" the administrator password? Please...

Comment: Your page `<title>` is *Our Portolio*. You might want to check that, too.

Comment: Also, I think you are referring JavaScript not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts are running before the DOM loads, and you are trying to access DOM Elements in those scripts.

If you don't know what DOM is Google it.

The solution is to run scripts on load event of Document.

```
document.onload = function(){
    //Your code here.
    ...
}
```

The `validateForm` works because you are just defining function and not accessing DOM directly.